# how to draw Fabric js strokeRect as in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am drawing shapes using html5 canvas library Fabric js :

Code :
`canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'empty',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 1}));`

But it is filling black in the middle area which I dont want .
I want the functionality like strokeRect in html5 canvas .
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        top : 100,
        left : 100,
        width : 50,
        height : 50,
        fill : '',
        stroke : 'white',
        strokeWidth : 1
    }));`

Answer (score 1):

Use `transparent` instead of `empty` to `fill` the rectangle.

Sample:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'transparent',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 1
}));
```

Comment: This also works : canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: '',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 1
}));